# edit picture online using javascript or php

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

hello everyone im trying to find any script or any librarly or any framwork to edit picture like this link

```
https://mydoormaker.com/en/
```

what i want is sometime i can change image and return it to the user
like if i have doors type

```
door1 door2 door3
```

and when the user select the door i can change the color of the door or add door handle or add glass to the door im good with `js` and `vuejs` and `php` and `laravel`
and here is some example from what i want

```
https://doordesigner.solidor.co.uk/
```

my need is how i can edit images and return it to the user and marriage tow or theree images using php or js thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thouht is to use canvas.

If you have enough asset png of doors, handles and glass you can simply put in one on another in similar way as layers in photoshop.

Your desired funtion will be `context.drawImage`.